# Is it possible to use maven only for running selenium plugin?

Tags: java, maven-2, selenium

Our pom.xml currently contains both the build settings, as well as execution of selenium using selenium-maven-plugin.

I would like to split it in to two pom files, one for the build and unit tests and the second one for executing selenium tests. (This way I could first build the project in Hudson, and after successful build execute Selenium tests using another project).

Is it possible to configure maven to only execute the selenium-maven-plugin?

Comment: Have you taken a look at using profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Put your functional (selenium) tests in a dedicated module with a dependency on the webapp.